# Spring Webmvc NoClassDefFoundError for class 'ModelAndViewDefiningException'

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

I have looked into this similar post here: [NoClassDefFoundError ModelAndViewDefiningException on spring+was8.5.5.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575032/noclassdeffounderror-modelandviewdefiningexception-on-springwas8-5-5-13), but it had no solutions.

I have unpacked my war file, and unpacked a library within it to verify it does contain the class mentioned in the NoClassDefFoundError:
spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar contains org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndViewDefiningException.class.

These are all my spring-related dependencies:

```
lib/metrics-spring-3.1.0 2 2.jar
lib/metrics-spring-3.1.0 2 3.jar
lib/metrics-spring-3.1.0 2.jar
lib/metrics-spring-3.1.0 3.jar
lib/metrics-spring-3.1.0.jar
lib/micrometer-spring-legacy-1.1.0.jar
lib/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-aspects-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-starter-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-cloud-aws-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-cloud-aws-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-cloud-starter-aws-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-data-commons-1.12.7.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-data-jpa-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-security-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-test-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
```

The last one only containing the specified class "ModelAndViewDefiningException" in the NoClassDefFoundError.

I have scanned through the unpacked jar file using my bash script to verify that the ModelAndViewDefiningException does indeed exist.

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in lib/*spring*.jar; do
    x=`jar -tvf "$filename" | grep 'ModelAndViewDefiningException'`
    if test ! -z "$x" 
    then
      echo $filename " class found is: " $x
    fi
done
```

It does indeed exist, through my script above:

```
lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar  class found is:  854 Wed Jan 25 13:16:28 AEDT 2017 org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndViewDefiningException.class
ip-192-168-0-13:WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because of maxed out file handles. This application runs on an Amazon instance production server, doing loads of volume. Running applications like Nginx, and some of our own applications.

That's why the JVM was unable to load in the class, because there weren't any file handles, hence the NoClassDefFoundError exception was being thrown.